# How to limit thumbnail images on Fb share?

Tags: facebook, share

I am working on a wp blog site. Currently *not* using og tags at all.

I use the social sharing toolkit plugin to allow visitors to share articles on Facebook.

**The problem:**
When FB share box pops up, all of the images on the page are shown as thumbnail options to be published along with the article information. In some cases over 20 sometimes.

How can i specify only 1 image to be shown in the available thumbnail options?

I'd like to do this so that visitors don't, for example, select a meaningless image (such as page ad images or layout components)?

I tried using `rel="image_src"` as suggested but it made no difference.

Thanks.

Comment: _“Currently not using og tags at all.”_ – change that.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me: I found out that even with OG meta tags Facebook Share plugin may present various thumbnails from my page, including all sorts of unwanted images. To work around it I add the wanted image with small size, first thing after the  tag:

```
<img src="image_wanted_as_thumbnail.whatever" style="width:1px;height:1px;">
```

But I always use the OG meta tags as well.